# Who distributes the flyers for the Preserve, and how?

Tags: sweet-tooth

The Preserve seems to be the refuge for hybrid children that Aimee runs at the zoo. What is less clear, though, is the source of the flyers urging people to contact it.

In favor of Aimee having spread them around: people calling the Preserve seem to be able to reach her without difficulty, and she has a pile of flyers on the wall.

Against her having spread them around: Doing so would require her to have a working printer with significant quantities of paper, a working plane with large quantities of fuel, which she also knew how to fly, and which she would take the risk of flying from her place of refuge despite trying to stay hidden, and despite the military presence in the area (presumably civilian planes on radar or in the air set off all kinds of alarms after the apocalypse). Or having a collaborator with the same resources. Also, calling the Preserve got Gus caught extremely quickly, which would make sense if the flyers were a trap from the military.

In short, then, who spreads the flyers for the Preserve around?